# Is there any way to start a Python program using Clojure or Lein?

Tags: python, clojure, leiningen

I had tried `clojure.java.shell`, but I think it's not exactly what I want. It's a future and the `stdout` is redirected.

I would like to run like `lein run xxx` to get `xxx.py` started, and then the info is printed on the console.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "it's a future"?

Comment: It returned a Future object in java.

Answer (score 2):

Is this not working?

```
(:out (clojure.java.shell/sh "python" "prog.py" "arg1" "arg2" :dir "/dir/to/prog.py"))
```

This should print the output to the console.